# Simplificar y optimizar un simulador de un juego en python

Tags: python, python-2.7

En los últimas semanas, con ayuda de la comunidad he desarrollado este programa que simula un juego de señales durante dos rondas con cuatro participantes. El juego que simula consiste en que en cada ronda cada participante muestre una señal y observe otra señal. Las señales mostradas y observadas son guardadas en unos diccionarios de memoria. En la primera ronda las señales (letras) son asignadas aleatoriamente, y en la segunda ronda las señales son asignadas dependiendo de una ecuación de probabilidad que tiene en cuenta el historial de memoria almacenado en los diccionarios.
El output muestra (en orden de participantes; participante 1, participante 2, participante 3, participante 4):

1. Señales mostradas por los participantes
2. Señales observadas por los participantes
3. Memoria acumulada de señales mostradas
4. Memoria acumulada de señales observadas

Me gustaría pedir ayuda a la comunidad para:

1. Simplificar este código para que haga lo mismo.
2. Permitir cambiar los emparejamientos iniciales y que los diccionarios de memoria guarden adecuadamente las señales.

   ```
   import random
   emparejamientos= ([[1,2],[3,4],  #ronda 1 (participante 1 juega con 2 y 3 con 4)
                     [1,3],[2,4]])   #ronda 2 (1 con 3 y 2 con 4)
   s1=1
   s2=0
   s3=0
   s4=0
   b=0.5
   x=0.5
   m=0.02

   Muestra_part1 = {"A":0,"B":0,"C":0,"D":0,"E":0,"F":0,"G":0,"H":0}
   Observa_part1 = {"A":0,"B":0,"C":0,"D":0,"E":0,"F":0,"G":0,"H":0}
   Muestra_part2 = {"A":0,"B":0,"C":0,"D":0,"E":0,"F":0,"G":0,"H":0}
   Observa_part2 = {"A":0,"B":0,"C":0,"D":0,"E":0,"F":0,"G":0,"H":0}
   Muestra_part3 = {"A":0,"B":0,"C":0,"D":0,"E":0,"F":0,"G":0,"H":0}
   Observa_part3 = {"A":0,"B":0,"C":0,"D":0,"E":0,"F":0,"G":0,"H":0}
   Muestra_part4 = {"A":0,"B":0,"C":0,"D":0,"E":0,"F":0,"G":0,"H":0}
   Observa_part4 = {"A":0,"B":0,"C":0,"D":0,"E":0,"F":0,"G":0,"H":0}

   #RONDA 1
   #Senales mostradas por cada participante en ronda 1
   S1, S2, S3, S4 = random.sample("ABCDEFGH", 4) #asignacion de senales random sin repeticion
   print "Senales mostradas en la generacion 1 \n {0}".format((S1, S2, S3, S4))

   #Almacen de senales mostradas en el diccionario (memoria de senales mostradas)
   for n in range(1):
       Muestra_part1[S1] += 1

   for n in range(1):
       Muestra_part2[S2] += 1

   for n in range(1):
       Muestra_part3[S3] += 1

   for n in range(1):
       Muestra_part4[S4] += 1

   #Almacen de senales observadas en el diccionario (memoria de senales observadas)
   if emparejamientos[0]==[1,2]:
       Observa_part1[S2] +=1
       Observa_part2[S1] +=1

   if emparejamientos[1]==[3,4]:
       Observa_part3[S4] += 1
       Observa_part4[S3] += 1

   #RONDA 2
   #Probabilidad para cada participante de mostrar una senal determinada en 2a ronda
   def with_b(muestra, observa, s):
       result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (1.0 - x) * muestra) + ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (x) * observa) + ((0.98) * 0 * s) + ((m / 8))
       if not (muestra == observa == 0):
           result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - b) * (1.0 - x) * muestra) + ((0.98) * (1.0 - b) * (x) * observa) + ((0.98) * b * s) + ((m / 8))
       return result

   Prob_S1_part1 = with_b(Muestra_part1[S1], Observa_part1[S1], s1)
   Prob_S2_part1 = with_b(Muestra_part1[S2], Observa_part1[S2], s2)
   Prob_S3_part1 = with_b(Muestra_part1[S3], Observa_part1[S3], s3)
   Prob_S4_part1 = with_b(Muestra_part1[S4], Observa_part1[S4], s4)

   Prob_S1_part2 = with_b(Muestra_part2[S1], Observa_part2[S1], s1)
   Prob_S2_part2 = with_b(Muestra_part2[S2], Observa_part2[S2], s2)
   Prob_S3_part2 = with_b(Muestra_part2[S3], Observa_part2[S3], s3)
   Prob_S4_part2 = with_b(Muestra_part2[S4], Observa_part2[S4], s4)

   Prob_S1_part3 = with_b(Muestra_part3[S1], Observa_part3[S1], s1)
   Prob_S2_part3 = with_b(Muestra_part3[S2], Observa_part3[S2], s2)
   Prob_S3_part3 = with_b(Muestra_part3[S3], Observa_part3[S3], s3)
   Prob_S4_part3 = with_b(Muestra_part3[S4], Observa_part3[S4], s4)

   Prob_S1_part4 = with_b(Muestra_part4[S1], Observa_part4[S1], s1)
   Prob_S2_part4 = with_b(Muestra_part4[S2], Observa_part4[S2], s2)
   Prob_S3_part4 = with_b(Muestra_part4[S3], Observa_part4[S3], s3)
   Prob_S4_part4 = with_b(Muestra_part4[S4], Observa_part4[S4], s4)

   #Senales que muestran los participantes en la RONDA 2. Asignadas segun las probabilidades dadas por la ecuacion de memorias
   opciones = [S1, S2, S3, S4]
   probabilidades1 = [Prob_S1_part1, Prob_S2_part1, Prob_S3_part1, Prob_S4_part1]
   probabilidades2 = [Prob_S1_part2, Prob_S2_part2, Prob_S3_part2, Prob_S4_part2]
   probabilidades3 = [Prob_S1_part3, Prob_S2_part3, Prob_S3_part3, Prob_S4_part3]
   probabilidades4 = [Prob_S1_part4, Prob_S2_part4, Prob_S3_part4, Prob_S4_part4]
   from random import random
   from bisect import bisect
   def choice(opciones, probs):
       probAcumuladas=[]
       aux = 0
       for p in probs:
           aux += p
           probAcumuladas.append(aux)
       r = random() * probAcumuladas[-1]
       op = bisect(probAcumuladas, r)
       return opciones[op]

   eleccion1 = choice(opciones, probabilidades1) #senal mostrada por participante 1 en ronda 2
   eleccion2 = choice(opciones, probabilidades2) #senal mostrada por participante 2 en ronda 2
   eleccion3 = choice(opciones, probabilidades3) #senal mostrada por participante 3 en ronda 2
   eleccion4 = choice(opciones, probabilidades4) #senal mostrada por participante 4 en ronda 2

   print "Senales mostradas en la generacion 2 \n {0}".format((eleccion1, eleccion2, eleccion3, eleccion4))

   #Almacen de senales mostradas en el diccionario (memoria de senales mostradas)
   if eleccion1 == S1:
       Muestra_part1[S1] +=1
   if eleccion1 == S2:
       Muestra_part1[S2] +=1
   if eleccion1 == S3:
       Muestra_part1[S3] +=1
   if eleccion1 == S4:
       Muestra_part1[S4] +=1

   if eleccion2 == S1:
       Muestra_part2[S1] +=1
   if eleccion2 == S2:
       Muestra_part2[S2] +=1
   if eleccion2 == S3:
       Muestra_part2[S3] +=1
   if eleccion2 == S4:
       Muestra_part2[S4] +=1

   if eleccion3 == S1:
       Muestra_part3[S1] +=1
   if eleccion3 == S2:
       Muestra_part3[S2] +=1
   if eleccion3 == S3:
       Muestra_part3[S3] +=1
   if eleccion3 == S4:
       Muestra_part3[S4] +=1

   if eleccion4 == S1:
       Muestra_part4[S1] +=1
   if eleccion4 == S2:
       Muestra_part4[S2] +=1
   if eleccion4 == S3:
       Muestra_part4[S3] +=1
   if eleccion4 == S4:
       Muestra_part4[S4] +=1

   print "Memoria acumulada de senales mostradas \n {0}".format ((Muestra_part1, Muestra_part2, Muestra_part3, Muestra_part4))

   #Almacen de senales observadas en el diccionario (memoria de senales observadas)
   if emparejamientos[2]==[1,3]:
       Observa_part1[eleccion3] +=1
       Observa_part3[eleccion1] +=1

   if emparejamientos[3]==[2,4]:
       Observa_part2[eleccion4] += 1
       Observa_part4[eleccion2] += 1

   print "Memorias acumulada de senales observadas \n {0}".format ((Observa_part1, Observa_part2, Observa_part3, Observa_part4))
   ```

Answer (score 2):

esto...

```
     #Almacen de senales mostradas en el diccionario (memoria de senales mostradas)
     for n in range(1):
         Muestra_part1[S1] += 1

     for n in range(1):
         Muestra_part2[S2] += 1

     for n in range(1):
          Muestra_part3[S3] += 1

     for n in range(1):
         Muestra_part4[S4] += 1
```

puede convertirse a esto...

```
         for n in range(1):
            Muestra_part1[S1] += 1
            Muestra_part2[S2] += 1
            Muestra_part3[S3] += 1
            Muestra_part4[S4] += 1
```