# Realizar x simulaciones y recoger los datos en un archivo CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7

Me gustaría saber cómo realizar 1000 simulaciones del siguiente código y recoger todos los datos de salida en un archivo CSV que contenga dos columnas (l1, l2) y ocho filas (ABCDEFGH) con las respectivas frecuencias de aparición de las letras a lo largo de las 1000 simulaciones.

```
import random
l1= random.choice("ABCDEFGH")
l2= random.choice("ABCDEFGH")
```

Las ocho filas deben representar las veces que `l1` y `l2` han resultado ser cada letra a lo largo de las 1000 simulaciones. Es decir, una tabla que recoja la fracuencia de aparición de cada letra en l1 y l2, a lo largo de las 1000 simulaciones. Para eso necesitamos recoger los datos en dos columnas (l1, l2) y ocho filas (ABCDEFGH).

Comment: Las veces que l1 ha resultado ser cada letra. Y las veces que l2 ha resultado ser cada letra. A lo largo de las 1000 simulaciones. Es decir, una tabla que recoja la fracuencia de aparición de cada letra en l1 y l2, a lo largo de las 1000 simulaciones. Para eso necesitamos recoger los datos en dos columnas (l1, l2) y ocho filas (ABCDEFGH).

Comment: Debes demostrar un mínimo de esfuerzo en resolver tu pregunta. Muéstranos hasta donde has llegado hasta ahora. Lee [mcve]

Comment: Intenta separar el problema en 2: por un lado realizar 1000 simulaciones almacenando los resultados, y por otro escribir esos resultados a un CSV. Avanza un poco y dinos dónde te quedas.

Comment: @David Isla he ido subiendo fragmentos del código que estoy elaborando en diferentes preguntas. A veces me han recomendado que no suba el código entero, sino que suba solo fragmentos pequeños para aprender y aplicar. Es lo que he hecho aquí. Puedes echar un vistazo a los códigos que he compartido y elaborado con esfuerzo en mi perfil. Sobre esta cuestión que planteo ahora no he conseguido averiguar mucho más que cómo abrir y cerrar un archivo CSV. Soy un principiante aún. Gracias por vuestros consejos.

Comment: Por supuesto no es recomendable pegar todo el código de tu aplicación o tardaríamos horas en estudiar que es lo que hace ;), pero básicamente lo que hacemos es resolver preguntas acerca de programación, por lo que lo ideal siempre es incluir el ejemplo de código más pequeño que puedas elaborar, que el resto lo podamos reproducir y que muestre claramente tu problema. Un saludo @pyring!

Comment: @astrojuanlu gracias por los consejos, son muy útiles. He desarrollado durante el último mes un código que simula un juego. El código es una versión mejorada de este [http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41726/simplificar-y-optimizar-un-simulador-de-un-juego-en-python] Estoy actualmente algo bloqueado porque no encuentro la manera de simular mi código x veces e ir recogiendo el output de las simulaciones de manera ordenada en un csv. Intentaré resolverlo, o si sigo bloqueado intentaré editar una pregunta con el código por si alguien sabe orientarme. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí lo que tienes que hacer es repetir la operación 1000 veces. Para esto, utiliza `range()`.

En cuanto a recoger los datos, un diccionario parece una buena solución. ¿Qué tal `defaultdict` para no tener que inicializarlo?

```
from collections import defaultdict

l1=defaultdict(int)
l2=defaultdict(int)

for i in range(1000):
    l1[random.choice("ABCDEFGH")]+=1
    l2[random.choice("ABCDEFGH")]+=1
```

Escribir en un archivo csv debería ser trivial.

Por ejemplo, a mí me devuelve:

```
In [20]: l1
Out[20]: 
defaultdict(int,
            {'A': 120,
             'B': 121,
             'C': 125,
             'D': 137,
             'E': 138,
             'F': 126,
             'G': 110,
             'H': 123})

In [21]: l2
Out[21]: 
defaultdict(int,
            {'A': 144,
             'B': 121,
             'C': 120,
             'D': 121,
             'E': 127,
             'F': 122,
             'G': 113,
             'H': 132})
```

Comment: gracias. Aunque la verdad es que estoy encontrando problemas para resolver el problema que tengo. Deseo realizar x simulaciones de un programa similar a este [http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41726/simplificar-y-optimizar-un-simulador-de-un-juego-en-python]. Pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo importando el módulo. Tampoco sé cómo podría almacenar ordenadamente en un csv el output de dicho programa a lo largo de las x simulaciones. Pongamos 1000 simulaciones.

Comment: @pyring no entiendo lo de _almacenar ordenadamente_. ¿No se trata de contar las ocurrencias? En cuanto a lo del módulo, necesitaría ver el código. ¡Junta lo que tengas y formula otra pregunta!

Comment: he subido mi código y reformulado la pregunta aquí [http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42391/ayuda-para-realizar-simulaciones-y-guardar-los-resultados-en-un-archivo-csv] Espero que esté más claro. Gracias en cualquier caso.