# Ayuda para realizar simulaciones y guardar los resultados en un archivo CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hace algunos días me pedían en los comentarios de otra pregunta que subiera mi código y reformulara la pregunta. Aquí va.

El siguiente código contiene una serie de variables y funciones, que definen un juego de señales según un modelo determinado. El output nos da las señales que muestra cada jugador en cada ronda.

Necesito saber cómo:

1. Simular este juego x veces (por ejemplo 1000). He conseguido hacerlo con execfile("Mimodulo.py"), pero no es útil para ir almacenando los resultados.
2. Almacenar en un archivo csv (filas (señales) y columnas (jugadores)), los resultados. Es decir, que el archivo csv contenga al final de las 1000 simulaciones la cantidad de cada tipo de señal que cada jugador ha producido en cada ronda. Esto es útil para hacer luego el análisis estadístico. Tan solo he conseguido abrir y cerrar un archivo CSV, pero me temo que estoy bloqueado.

Aquí está el código:

```
import random
##### Variables ######
emparejamientos= ([[1,2],[3,4],  #ronda 1 (participante 1 juega con 2 y 3 con 4)
                   [1,3],[2,4],  #ronda 2 (1 con 3 y 2 con 4)
                   [1,4],[2,3]]) #ronda 3 (1 con 4 y 2 con 3)

#Parejas de cada participante en cada ronda (empezando por la ronda 1). 
pareja_part1= [2,3,4]
pareja_part2= [1,4,3]
pareja_part3= [4,1,2]
pareja_part4= [3,2,1]

#Parametros del modelo
s1=1   
s2=0
s3=0
s4=0
b=0.5  
x=0.5  
m=0.02
round=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6] #rounds

#Senales
S1="S1"
S2="S2"
S3="S3"
S4="S4"
opciones = [S1, S2, S3, S4]

#Diccionarios de memoria
Muestra_part1 = {"S1":0,"S2":0,"S3":0,"S4":0}
Observa_part1 = {"S1":0,"S2":0,"S3":0,"S4":0}
Muestra_part2 = {"S1":0,"S2":0,"S3":0,"S4":0}
Observa_part2 = {"S1":0,"S2":0,"S3":0,"S4":0}
Muestra_part3 = {"S1":0,"S2":0,"S3":0,"S4":0}
Observa_part3 = {"S1":0,"S2":0,"S3":0,"S4":0}
Muestra_part4 = {"S1":0,"S2":0,"S3":0,"S4":0}
Observa_part4 = {"S1":0,"S2":0,"S3":0,"S4":0}

##### Funciones #####
#Almacen de senales mostradas en el diccionario de memoria Muestra_partx
def mem_mostradas(e, memoria):
    if e == S1:
        memoria[S1] +=1
    if e == S2:
        memoria[S2] +=1
    if e == S3:
        memoria[S3] +=1
    if e == S4:
        memoria[S4] +=1
    return memoria

#Almacen de senales observadas en el diccionario de memoria Observa_partx
def mem_observadas(pareja_part, memoria):
    if pareja_part == 1:
         memoria[eleccion1] +=1
    if pareja_part == 2:
         memoria[eleccion2] +=1
    if pareja_part == 3:
         memoria[eleccion3] +=1
    if pareja_part == 4:
         memoria[eleccion4] +=1
    return memoria

#Probabilidad para cada participante de mostrar una senal determinada en una ronda
def with_b(muestra, observa, s, r):
    result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (1.0 - x) * muestra/r) + ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (x) * observa/r) + ((0.98) * 0 * s) + ((m / 8))
    if not (muestra == observa == 0):
        result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - b) * (1.0 - x) * muestra/r) + ((0.98) * (1.0 - b) * (x) * observa/r) + ((0.98) * b * s) + ((m / 8))
    return result

#Funcion que arroja la opcion que cada participante elige para mostrar
from random import random
from bisect import bisect
def choice(opciones, probs):
    probAcumuladas=[]
    aux = 0
    for p in probs:
        aux += p
        probAcumuladas.append(aux)
    r = random() * probAcumuladas[-1]
    op = bisect(probAcumuladas, r)
    return opciones[op]

##### Juego #####
#RONDA 1
#Senales mostradas por cada participante en ronda 1
eleccion1=S1
eleccion2=S2
eleccion3=S3
eleccion4=S4
print "Senales mostradas en la generacion 1 \n jugador1: {0}, jugador2: {1}, jugador3: {2}, jugador4: {3}".format(S1, S2, S3, S4)

#Almacen de senales mostradas en el diccionario (memoria de senales mostradas)
Muestra_part1=mem_mostradas(eleccion1,Muestra_part1)
Muestra_part2=mem_mostradas(eleccion2,Muestra_part2)
Muestra_part3=mem_mostradas(eleccion3,Muestra_part3)
Muestra_part4=mem_mostradas(eleccion4,Muestra_part4)

#Almacen de senales observadas en el diccionario (memoria de senales observadas)
Observa_part1=mem_observadas(pareja_part1[0], Observa_part1)
Observa_part2=mem_observadas(pareja_part2[0], Observa_part2)
Observa_part3=mem_observadas(pareja_part3[0], Observa_part3)
Observa_part4=mem_observadas(pareja_part4[0], Observa_part4)

#RONDA 2
#Probabilidad para cada participante de mostrar una senal determinada en 2a ronda
Prob_S1_part1 = with_b(Muestra_part1[S1], Observa_part1[S1], s1, round[1])
Prob_S2_part1 = with_b(Muestra_part1[S2], Observa_part1[S2], s2, round[1])
Prob_S3_part1 = with_b(Muestra_part1[S3], Observa_part1[S3], s3, round[1])
Prob_S4_part1 = with_b(Muestra_part1[S4], Observa_part1[S4], s4, round[1])

Prob_S1_part2 = with_b(Muestra_part2[S1], Observa_part2[S1], s1, round[1])
Prob_S2_part2 = with_b(Muestra_part2[S2], Observa_part2[S2], s2, round[1])
Prob_S3_part2 = with_b(Muestra_part2[S3], Observa_part2[S3], s3, round[1])
Prob_S4_part2 = with_b(Muestra_part2[S4], Observa_part2[S4], s4, round[1])

Prob_S1_part3 = with_b(Muestra_part3[S1], Observa_part3[S1], s1, round[1])
Prob_S2_part3 = with_b(Muestra_part3[S2], Observa_part3[S2], s2, round[1])
Prob_S3_part3 = with_b(Muestra_part3[S3], Observa_part3[S3], s3, round[1])
Prob_S4_part3 = with_b(Muestra_part3[S4], Observa_part3[S4], s4, round[1])

Prob_S1_part4 = with_b(Muestra_part4[S1], Observa_part4[S1], s1, round[1])
Prob_S2_part4 = with_b(Muestra_part4[S2], Observa_part4[S2], s2, round[1])
Prob_S3_part4 = with_b(Muestra_part4[S3], Observa_part4[S3], s3, round[1])
Prob_S4_part4 = with_b(Muestra_part4[S4], Observa_part4[S4], s4, round[1])

probabilidades1 = [Prob_S1_part1, Prob_S2_part1, Prob_S3_part1, Prob_S4_part1]
probabilidades2 = [Prob_S1_part2, Prob_S2_part2, Prob_S3_part2, Prob_S4_part2]
probabilidades3 = [Prob_S1_part3, Prob_S2_part3, Prob_S3_part3, Prob_S4_part3]
probabilidades4 = [Prob_S1_part4, Prob_S2_part4, Prob_S3_part4, Prob_S4_part4]

#Senales que muestran los participantes en la RONDA 2. Asignadas segun las probabilidades dadas por la ecuacion de memorias
eleccion1 = choice(opciones, probabilidades1) #senal mostrada por participante 1 en ronda 2
eleccion2 = choice(opciones, probabilidades2) #senal mostrada por participante 2 en ronda 2
eleccion3 = choice(opciones, probabilidades3) #senal mostrada por participante 3 en ronda 2
eleccion4 = choice(opciones, probabilidades4) #senal mostrada por participante 4 en ronda 2

print "Senales mostradas en la generacion 2 \n jugador1: {0}, jugador2: {1}, jugador3: {2}, jugador4: {3}".format(eleccion1, eleccion2, eleccion3, eleccion4)

#Almacen de senales mostradas en el diccionario (memoria de senales mostradas)
Muestra_part1=mem_mostradas(eleccion1,Muestra_part1)
Muestra_part2=mem_mostradas(eleccion2,Muestra_part2)
Muestra_part3=mem_mostradas(eleccion3,Muestra_part3)
Muestra_part4=mem_mostradas(eleccion4,Muestra_part4)

#Almacen de senales observadas en el diccionario (memoria de senales observadas)
Observa_part1=mem_observadas(pareja_part1[1], Observa_part1)
Observa_part2=mem_observadas(pareja_part2[1], Observa_part2)
Observa_part3=mem_observadas(pareja_part3[1], Observa_part3)
Observa_part4=mem_observadas(pareja_part4[1], Observa_part4)

#RONDA 3
#Probabilidad para cada participante de mostrar una senal determinada en 3a ronda
Prob_S1_part1 = with_b(Muestra_part1[S1], Observa_part1[S1], s1, round[2])
Prob_S2_part1 = with_b(Muestra_part1[S2], Observa_part1[S2], s2, round[2])
Prob_S3_part1 = with_b(Muestra_part1[S3], Observa_part1[S3], s3, round[2])
Prob_S4_part1 = with_b(Muestra_part1[S4], Observa_part1[S4], s4, round[2])

Prob_S1_part2 = with_b(Muestra_part2[S1], Observa_part2[S1], s1, round[2])
Prob_S2_part2 = with_b(Muestra_part2[S2], Observa_part2[S2], s2, round[2])
Prob_S3_part2 = with_b(Muestra_part2[S3], Observa_part2[S3], s3, round[2])
Prob_S4_part2 = with_b(Muestra_part2[S4], Observa_part2[S4], s4, round[2])

Prob_S1_part3 = with_b(Muestra_part3[S1], Observa_part3[S1], s1, round[2])
Prob_S2_part3 = with_b(Muestra_part3[S2], Observa_part3[S2], s2, round[2])
Prob_S3_part3 = with_b(Muestra_part3[S3], Observa_part3[S3], s3, round[2])
Prob_S4_part3 = with_b(Muestra_part3[S4], Observa_part3[S4], s4, round[2])

Prob_S1_part4 = with_b(Muestra_part4[S1], Observa_part4[S1], s1, round[2])
Prob_S2_part4 = with_b(Muestra_part4[S2], Observa_part4[S2], s2, round[2])
Prob_S3_part4 = with_b(Muestra_part4[S3], Observa_part4[S3], s3, round[2])
Prob_S4_part4 = with_b(Muestra_part4[S4], Observa_part4[S4], s4, round[2])

probabilidades1 = [Prob_S1_part1, Prob_S2_part1, Prob_S3_part1, Prob_S4_part1]
probabilidades2 = [Prob_S1_part2, Prob_S2_part2, Prob_S3_part2, Prob_S4_part2]
probabilidades3 = [Prob_S1_part3, Prob_S2_part3, Prob_S3_part3, Prob_S4_part3]
probabilidades4 = [Prob_S1_part4, Prob_S2_part4, Prob_S3_part4, Prob_S4_part4]

#Senales que muestran los participantes en la RONDA 3. Asignadas segun las probabilidades dadas por la ecuacion de memorias
eleccion1 = choice(opciones, probabilidades1) #senal mostrada por participante 1 en ronda 3
eleccion2 = choice(opciones, probabilidades2) #senal mostrada por participante 2 en ronda 3
eleccion3 = choice(opciones, probabilidades3) #senal mostrada por participante 3 en ronda 3
eleccion4 = choice(opciones, probabilidades4) #senal mostrada por participante 4 en ronda 3

print "Senales mostradas en la generacion 3 \n jugador1: {0}, jugador2: {1}, jugador3: {2}, jugador4: {3}".format(eleccion1, eleccion2, eleccion3, eleccion4)

#Almacen de senales mostradas en el diccionario (memoria de senales mostradas)
Muestra_part1=mem_mostradas(eleccion1,Muestra_part1)
Muestra_part2=mem_mostradas(eleccion2,Muestra_part2)
Muestra_part3=mem_mostradas(eleccion3,Muestra_part3)
Muestra_part4=mem_mostradas(eleccion4,Muestra_part4)

#Almacen de senales observadas en el diccionario (memoria de senales observadas)
Observa_part1=mem_observadas(pareja_part1[2], Observa_part1)
Observa_part2=mem_observadas(pareja_part2[2], Observa_part2)
Observa_part3=mem_observadas(pareja_part3[2], Observa_part3)
Observa_part4=mem_observadas(pareja_part4[2], Observa_part4)
```

El output en una simulación ejemplo es el siguiente:

```
Senales mostradas en la generacion 1 
 jugador1: S1, jugador2: S2, jugador3: S3, jugador4: S4
Senales mostradas en la generacion 2 
 jugador1: S1, jugador2: S1, jugador3: S3, jugador4: S4
Senales mostradas en la generacion 3 
 jugador1: S2, jugador2: S1, jugador3: S1, jugador4: S1
```

Por lo tanto, se busca ir almacenando en un archivo CSV, durante 1000 simulaciones, las señales que cada jugador ha generando en cada ronda.

Un ejemplo de cómo sería útil almacenar los resultados en un CSV para el posterior análisis estadístico es el siguiente. En el ejemplo, las columnas RONDAX muestran el número de veces que se ha elegido cada señal (los números de esta imagen no corresponden a ninguna simulación con el programa, y por eso los sumatorios son inconsistentes, pues se trata solo de un ejemplo para ilustrar el formato de la tabla).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Edición (11.01.2016):**

Partiendo de la última versión del código compartido por @FJSevilla, me gustaría poder ir un poco más allá. De cara al análisis estadístico de los datos sería interesante obtener no ya 1000 simulaciones, sino x muestras de 1000 simulaciones.

Utilizando el mismo código, la tabla de resultados que en este caso se pretende obtener es como la siguiente (ejemplificando cómo sería un CSV que almacenararía los resultados de 3 muestras de 1000 simulaciones del juego completo):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde en "muestra" el número 1 hace referencia a las primeras 1000 simulaciones, 2 hace referencia a las segundas 1000 simulaciones y así sucesivamente. Donde "ronda" hace referencia al número de ronda dentro del juego. Donde "jugador" hace referencia al número de jugador.

Nótese que en este caso se incluyen los parámetros b, x y m en la tabla, y que los números en las columnas "Senalx" hacen referencia a las veces que cada señal ha sido elegida en cada ronda.

Es una configuración del orden de los datos diferente a la que teníamos, pero que facilitaría la comparación estadística. ¿Alguna mano amiga con esto?

Comment: ¿Porque no intentas embeber todo el código dentro de un ciclo? puede ser `while` o `for` acompañado de un `range()` y cada vez que termine una iteración guardas los resultados en el csv, que puedes hacer con `with open('archivo.csv', 'a') as escribir` y luego almacenas tu resultado en un string formateado con `.format()` y ya únicamente lo escribes así: `escribir.write(string)` eso me parece podría funcionar.

Comment: Por aclarar un poco, ¿Lo que quieres es simular ese mismo código 1000 veces (1000 juegos de 3 rondas) o simular un juego de 1000 rondas?

Comment: @FJSevilla Lo que se busca es simular ese mismo juego 1000 veces (1000 juegos de 3 rondas). Aunque es verdad que en el futuro me gustaría implementar la posibilidad de hacer más rondas con más participantes, de momento estoy en el primer paso.

Comment: @FJSevilla he editado la pregunta con la intención de tomar varias muestras de x simulaciones y mejorar el csv de salida de cara al análisis estadístico. Todo sobre la base de la última versión del código que compartiste. Creo que como es una pregunta relacionada con el hilo está bien editarla aquí, aunque si no produce efectos, puedo formular una nueva pregunta con lo que se busca y lo trabajado hasta el momento.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He estado viendo las preguntas anteriores y en base a esto te dejo una aproximación usando POO. De esta forma el código se reduce y se hace escalable fácilmente ya que permite usar un número indeterminado de señales, de jugadores y de rondas. Algunas aclaraciones:

- He eliminado la variable `round` ya que, según creo, solo usas la lista para numerar la ronda en la que estás, es decir siempre es de la forma:

  ```
  round= [0,1,2,3,...,n]
  ```

  Si no es de esta forma se puede modificar fácilmente para que el constructor acepte la lista como variable.
- El funcionamiento del método `generar_senales()` es:

  - En la ronda 1 las señales de cada participante vienen determinadas por el orden de los parámetros jugadores y senales que le pasamos al constructor. Por ejemplo:

    ```
    jugadores = [1,2,3,4]
    senales = ['a', 'b', 'r', 'n']
    ```

    En la primera ronda el jugador 1 muestra la señal 'a', el 2 la señal 'b', el 3 la señal 'r' y el 4 la señal 'n'.
  - En la segunda ronda y posteriores usa las señales de la primera ronda para generar cada señal aleatoriamente y de acuerdo a las probabilidades para cada jugador y señal (usando las funciones `with_b` y `choise`).

  El método `generar_senales()` es un generador (`yield`) y retorna un diccionario con la señal aleatoria de cada jugador, de la forma:

  ```
  {1: 'S8', 2: 'S6', 3: 'S5', 4: 'S1', 5: 'S3', 6: 'S7'}
  ```

  Este mismo diccionario es el que se usa para crear la fila correspondiente del `csv`
- Las variales `s1`, `s2`, `s3`, `s4` las paso dentro de una lista llamada `s`, de esta forma podemos definir cualquier número de jugadores y señales.
- La forma de pasar los emparejamientos también la he modificado, ahora cada ronda es una lista que contiene dentro los emparejamientos. De esta forma queda más intuitivo. No obstante se podría seguir usando tu forma con algunas modificaciones.
- El `csv` tiene como cabecera (primera fila) los nombres de los jugadores. El resto de filas son las rondas (señal mostrada por cada jugador).

Como muestra en la siguiente ejecución simulamos un juego de 4 rondas con 6 jugadores:

```
from random import random, sample
from bisect import bisect
import csv

class Partida():
    def __init__(self, jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, s, b, x, m):
        self.emparejamientos = emparejamientos
        self.senales = senales
        self.s = s
        self.b = b
        self.x = x
        self.m = m
        self.jugadores = {nombre: Partida.Jugador(senales)
                            for pareja in emparejamientos[0]
                                for nombre in pareja}
        self.memoria = list()


    def generar_senales(self):

        def with_b(muestra, observa, s, r):
            if not (muestra == observa == 0):
                result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra/r) + ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (self.x) * observa/r) + ((0.98) * self.b * s) + ((self.m / 8))
            else:
                result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra/r) + ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (self.x) * observa/r) + ((0.98) * 0 * s) + ((self.m / 8))
            return result

        def choice(opciones, probs):
            probAcumuladas = list()
            aux = 0
            for p in probs:
                aux += p
                probAcumuladas.append(aux)
            r = random() * probAcumuladas[-1]
            op = bisect(probAcumuladas, r)
            return opciones[op]

        yield dict(zip(self.jugadores.keys(), self.senales))


        r = 1
        while True:
            eleccs = dict.fromkeys(self.jugadores.keys())
            for nombre, inst in self.jugadores.items():
                probs = [with_b(inst.mem_mostradas[op], inst.men_observadas[op], self.s[indx], r)
                            for indx, op in enumerate(self.senales)]
                eleccs[nombre] = choice(self.senales, probs)
            r += 1
            yield eleccs


    def jugar(self):
        gen_sens =  self.generar_senales()
        for n, ronda in enumerate(self.emparejamientos):
            senales = next(gen_sens)
            self.memoria.append(senales)

            for jugador1, jugador2 in ronda:
                self.jugadores[jugador1].men_observadas[senales[jugador2]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].men_observadas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador1].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador2]] += 1


    class Jugador():
        def __init__(self, senales):
            self.mem_mostradas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}
            self.men_observadas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}



def main():
    jugadores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    senales = ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6']
    emparejamientos = [[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)],
                       [(1,5),(2,4),(3,6)],
                       [(1,6),(2,3),(4,5)],
                       [(1,3),(4,6),(2,5)]]

    s=[1,0,0,0,0,0]
    b=0.5
    x=0.5
    m=0.02

    with open('salida.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile,fieldnames = jugadores, delimiter=',',
                        quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        writer.writeheader()

        for _ in range(1000):
            juego = Partida(jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, s, b, x, m)
            juego.jugar()
            for ronda in juego.memoria:
                writer.writerow(ronda)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Esto nos genera un `csv` que abierto con LibreOffice (para ver más visualmente como quedan los datos) queda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso el csv tiene 6 columnas (1 por jugador) y 4001 filas (la primera es la cabecera y las otras 4000 corresponde a las mil simulaciones del juego de 4 rondas). Para adaptarlo a otros parámetrso solo tienes que modificarlos en la función `main()`

Hay muchas formas de hacer esto, en este caso yo lo que hago es que guardo en una lista de diccionarios (`self.memoria`) las elecciones de cada ronda y lugo la uso para ir creando el csv. Para manejar el csv en sí uso la librería estándar [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) de Python.

**Edición:**

Si deseas obtener las frecuencias con que cada jugador a mostrado cada señal a partir del `csv` puedes hacer algo así:

```
import collections
import csv
import itertools



with open('salida.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    header = reader.next()
    transpuesta = itertools.izip(*reader)

    print 'Estadisticas:'

    for n, jugador in enumerate(transpuesta):
        print '    Jugador {0}:'.format(header[n])
        t = len(jugador)*1.0
        for (k,v) in collections.Counter(jugador).iteritems():
            print "        Senal {0} mostrada {1} veces. Frecuencia: {2}%".format(k, v, v/t*100)
```

`csv.reader` crea un generador que itera sobre las filas del `csv`, si lo que quiereses obtener las columnas, una solución es tratarlo como una matriz y usar su transpuesta (descartando la primera fila que es la cabecera con los nombres), para ello podemos usar [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip). Para contar las frecuencias es muy útil [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Este código lo puedes usar dentro de la función `main` anterior, para ello mueve los import al inicio del módulo. Unas salida ejemplo sería:

> Estadisticas:
>    Jugador 1:
>     Senal S3 mostrada 626 veces. Frecuencia: 15.65%
>     Senal S2 mostrada 626 veces. Frecuencia: 15.65%
>     Senal S1 mostrada 739 veces. Frecuencia: 18.475%
>     Senal S6 mostrada 663 veces. Frecuencia: 16.575%
>     Senal S5 mostrada 683 veces. Frecuencia: 17.075%
>     Senal S4 mostrada 663 veces. Frecuencia: 16.575%
>    Jugador 2:
>     Senal S3 mostrada 692 veces. Frecuencia: 17.3%
>     Senal S2 mostrada 701 veces. Frecuencia: 17.525%
>     Senal S1 mostrada 693 veces. Frecuencia: 17.325%
>     Senal S6 mostrada 572 veces. Frecuencia: 14.3%
>     Senal S5 mostrada 687 veces. Frecuencia: 17.175%
>     Senal S4 mostrada 655 veces. Frecuencia: 16.375%
>    Jugador 3:
>     Senal S3 mostrada 708 veces. Frecuencia: 17.7%
>     Senal S2 mostrada 730 veces. Frecuencia: 18.25%
>     Senal S1 mostrada 658 veces. Frecuencia: 16.45%
>     Senal S6 mostrada 652 veces. Frecuencia: 16.3%
>     Senal S5 mostrada 647 veces. Frecuencia: 16.175%
>     Senal S4 mostrada 605 veces. Frecuencia: 15.125%
>    Jugador 4:
>     Senal S3 mostrada 696 veces. Frecuencia: 17.4%
>     Senal S2 mostrada 648 veces. Frecuencia: 16.2%
>     Senal S1 mostrada 685 veces. Frecuencia: 17.125%
>     Senal S6 mostrada 694 veces. Frecuencia: 17.35%
>     Senal S5 mostrada 639 veces. Frecuencia: 15.975%
>     Senal S4 mostrada 638 veces. Frecuencia: 15.95%
>    Jugador 5:
>     Senal S3 mostrada 659 veces. Frecuencia: 16.475%
>     Senal S2 mostrada 594 veces. Frecuencia: 14.85%
>     Senal S1 mostrada 643 veces. Frecuencia: 16.075%
>     Senal S6 mostrada 686 veces. Frecuencia: 17.15%
>     Senal S5 mostrada 663 veces. Frecuencia: 16.575%
>     Senal S4 mostrada 755 veces. Frecuencia: 18.875%
>    Jugador 6:
>     Senal S3 mostrada 553 veces. Frecuencia: 13.825%
>     Senal S2 mostrada 659 veces. Frecuencia: 16.475%
>     Senal S1 mostrada 672 veces. Frecuencia: 16.8%
>     Senal S6 mostrada 721 veces. Frecuencia: 18.025%
>     Senal S5 mostrada 681 veces. Frecuencia: 17.025%
>     Senal S4 mostrada 714 veces. Frecuencia: 17.85%

Si vas a trabajar mucho con archivos `csv` y datos te recomiendo que te mires [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

**Edición 2:**
Te dejo el código con la funcion `main` modificada para que genere el `csv` que deseas de acuerdo a la edición de tu pregunta.

```
from random import random, sample
from bisect import bisect
import csv

class Partida():
    def __init__(self, jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, s, b, x, m):
        self.emparejamientos = emparejamientos
        self.senales = senales
        self.s = s
        self.b = b
        self.x = x
        self.m = m
        self.jugadores = {nombre: Partida.Jugador(senales)
                            for pareja in emparejamientos[0]
                                for nombre in pareja}
        self.memoria = list()


    def generar_senales(self):

        def with_b(muestra, observa, s, r):
            if not (muestra == observa == 0):
                result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra/r) + ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (self.x) * observa/r) + ((0.98) * self.b * s) + ((self.m / 8))
            else:
                result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra/r) + ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (self.x) * observa/r) + ((0.98) * 0 * s) + ((self.m / 8))
            return result

        def choice(opciones, probs):
            probAcumuladas = list()
            aux = 0
            for p in probs:
                aux += p
                probAcumuladas.append(aux)
            r = random() * probAcumuladas[-1]
            op = bisect(probAcumuladas, r)
            return opciones[op]

        yield dict(zip(self.jugadores.keys(), self.senales))


        r = 1
        while True:
            eleccs = dict.fromkeys(self.jugadores.keys())
            for nombre, inst in self.jugadores.items():
                probs = [with_b(inst.mem_mostradas[op], inst.men_observadas[op], self.s[indx], r)
                            for indx, op in enumerate(self.senales)]
                eleccs[nombre] = choice(self.senales, probs)
            r += 1
            yield eleccs


    def jugar(self):
        gen_sens =  self.generar_senales()
        for n, ronda in enumerate(self.emparejamientos):
            senales = next(gen_sens)
            self.memoria.append(senales)

            for jugador1, jugador2 in ronda:
                self.jugadores[jugador1].men_observadas[senales[jugador2]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].men_observadas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador1].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador2]] += 1


    class Jugador():
        def __init__(self, senales):
            self.mem_mostradas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}
            self.men_observadas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}



def main():
    jugadores = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    senales = ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', ]
    emparejamientos = [[(1,2),(3,4)],
                       [(1,3),(2,4)],
                       [(1,4),(2,3)]]
    s=[1,0,0,0]
    b=0.5
    x=0.5
    m=0.02

    rondas = ['RONDA' + str(n+1) for n in range(len(emparejamientos))]
    estadisticas = {jugador:{senal:[0 for ronda in rondas]
                        for senal in senales}
                            for jugador in jugadores}

    for _ in range(1000):
        juego = Partida(jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, s, b, x, m)
        juego.jugar()
        for n, ronda in enumerate(juego.memoria):
            for jugador, senal in ronda.items():
                estadisticas[jugador][senal][n] += 1

    with open('salida.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        writer =csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                    quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        writer.writerow(['JUGADOR', 'SENAL'] + rondas)

        for jugador in jugadores:
            for senal in senales:
                writer.writerow([jugador, senal]+estadisticas[jugador][senal])



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Simulando tu ejemplo obtenemos un `csv` como el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchísimas gracias. La respuesta es impresionante. Tan solo un par de dudas sobre tu código. En la función def with_b el valor r debe corresponder a la ronda para la que se hace el cálculo menos 1 (como en mi código). Esto es porque se tiene en cuenta la memoria de las rondas pasadas. En tu código está implementado igual, ¿verdad? Aún me cuesta verlo.

Comment: Por otra parte, sí me gustaría que el código asignara en primera ronda las señales sin random. Es decir, como en mi último código, S1="S1", S2="S2", etc... De esta forma podemos hacer una estadística final que corresponda a las señales elegidas por cada jugador controlando el factor de elección inicial. Es más interesante hacerlo así para ver cómo afecta el modelo matemático a la evolución del lenguaje.

Comment: Finalmente, las frecuencias que me gustaría conseguir son, efectivamente, las de la cantidad de veces que los jugadores han elegido cada señal. Pero para el análisis estadístico lo desearía hacer ronda por ronda. Por lo que necesitaré saber cómo utilizar el código para colectar la frecuencia con que han elegido cada señal en cada ronda. Te agradezco mucho todo esto que compartes, y tu tiempo. :)

Comment: @pyring en cuanto a lo del valor de r: en la primera ronda no se usa (se asignan las señales manualmente), en las segunda vale 1, en la tercera 2... creo que es lo que deseas. En cuanto a la segunda cuestión, he modificado el código para que en la primera ronda asigne manualmente como deseas. En cuanto al cálculo de las frecuencias no termino de aclararme, ¿quieres calcular por cada ronda (cada fila del csv) la frecuencia de cada señal desde el inicio de la simulación hasta ese momento? Un pequeño ejemplo con pocos datos puede venir bién para aclarar lo que deseas.

Comment: En cuanto al CSV. Lo óptimo sería poder disponer de un archivo CSV en el que almacenar las veces que cada jugador, en cada ronda, ha elegido cada señal a lo largo de las 1000 simulaciones. De esta manera, si realizamos 1000 simulaciones con otros parámetros de la ecuación matemática, podremos comparar los resultados de manera más sencilla con algún programa informático de estadística. Edito la pregunta arriba para poner una tabla de ejemplo. A ver qué te parece.

Comment: @pyring he actualizado la respuesta, al final te dejo el código modificado que creo que te genera el `csv` que deseas. También he corregido (en ambos códigos) un error tonto por mi parte en la clase principal que generaba fallos al guardar las elecciones en el atributo `self.memoria`. Creo que ahora todo está bien pero si observas algo raro no dudes en comentarlo.

Comment: esta actualización del código da en el clavo. Es exactamente lo que necesitaba. Voy a verificar que todo esté correcto y a echar un vistazo a pandas, tal y como me has recomendado, también a R. Pero de momento, este código y los CSV que genera son más que útiles para empezar a hacer cosas interesantes con cualquier software estadístico como SPSS. Muchas gracias por el tiempo y sí, seguro que seguiré preguntando. Queda mucho que aprender y aplicar :)

Comment: @pyring hay muchos módulos y bibliotecas para el análisis estadístico, BigData y machine learning a los que puedes ir echando un vistazo :). entre ellas `Numpy`, `SciPy`, `Pandas`, `Matplotlib`, `SymPy` o `SciKits`. además tienes la posibilidad de usar [IPython](https://ipython.org/) junto a ellos. Junto a R y SAS, Python es uno de los lenguajes más usados en este ámbito.

Answer (score 2):

Como te han indicado en un comentario, puedes, simplemente, envolver la parte del juego en un bucle e ir guardando la información que necesitas de la forma en que la necesites. Por ejemplo, podría ser así:

```
from random import random
from bisect import bisect
##### Variables ######
emparejamientos= ([[1,2],[3,4],  #ronda 1 (participante 1 juega con 2 y 3 con 4)
                   [1,3],[2,4],  #ronda 2 (1 con 3 y 2 con 4)
                   [1,4],[2,3]]) #ronda 3 (1 con 4 y 2 con 3)

#Parejas de cada participante en cada ronda (empezando por la ronda 1). 
pareja_part1= [2,3,4]
pareja_part2= [1,4,3]
pareja_part3= [4,1,2]
pareja_part4= [3,2,1]

#Parametros del modelo
s1=1   
s2=0
s3=0
s4=0
b=0.5  
x=0.5  
m=0.02
round=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6] #rounds

#Senales
S1="S1"
S2="S2"
S3="S3"
S4="S4"
opciones = [S1, S2, S3, S4]

#Diccionarios de memoria
Muestra_part1 = {"S1":0,"S2":0,"S3":0,"S4":0}
Observa_part1 = {"S1":0,"S2":0,"S3":0,"S4":0}
Muestra_part2 = {"S1":0,"S2":0,"S3":0,"S4":0}
Observa_part2 = {"S1":0,"S2":0,"S3":0,"S4":0}
Muestra_part3 = {"S1":0,"S2":0,"S3":0,"S4":0}
Observa_part3 = {"S1":0,"S2":0,"S3":0,"S4":0}
Muestra_part4 = {"S1":0,"S2":0,"S3":0,"S4":0}
Observa_part4 = {"S1":0,"S2":0,"S3":0,"S4":0}

##### Funciones #####
#Almacen de senales mostradas en el diccionario de memoria Muestra_partx
def mem_mostradas(e, memoria):
    if e == S1:
        memoria[S1] +=1
    if e == S2:
        memoria[S2] +=1
    if e == S3:
        memoria[S3] +=1
    if e == S4:
        memoria[S4] +=1
    return memoria

#Almacen de senales observadas en el diccionario de memoria Observa_partx
def mem_observadas(pareja_part, memoria):
    if pareja_part == 1:
         memoria[eleccion1] +=1
    if pareja_part == 2:
         memoria[eleccion2] +=1
    if pareja_part == 3:
         memoria[eleccion3] +=1
    if pareja_part == 4:
         memoria[eleccion4] +=1
    return memoria

#Probabilidad para cada participante de mostrar una senal determinada en una ronda
def with_b(muestra, observa, s, r):
    result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (1.0 - x) * muestra/r) + ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (x) * observa/r) + ((0.98) * 0 * s) + ((m / 8))
    if not (muestra == observa == 0):
        result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - b) * (1.0 - x) * muestra/r) + ((0.98) * (1.0 - b) * (x) * observa/r) + ((0.98) * b * s) + ((m / 8))
    return result

#Funcion que arroja la opcion que cada participante elige para mostrar
def choice(opciones, probs):
    probAcumuladas=[]
    aux = 0
    for p in probs:
        aux += p
        probAcumuladas.append(aux)
    r = random() * probAcumuladas[-1]
    op = bisect(probAcumuladas, r)
    return opciones[op]

with open('resultados.csv', 'w') as fichero: ##################################
    fichero.write('Generación,Jugador01,Jugador02,Jugador03,Jugador04\n') #####
    output = "{0:>10},{1:>9},{2:>9},{3:>9},{4:>9}\n" ##########################
    for i in range(1000): #####################################################
        ##### Juego #####

        #Senales mostradas por cada participante en ronda 1
        eleccion1=S1
        eleccion2=S2
        eleccion3=S3
        eleccion4=S4
        if i == 0: ############################################################
            fichero.write(output.format(i, S1, S2, S3, S4)) ###################

        #Almacen de senales mostradas en el diccionario (memoria de senales mostradas)
        Muestra_part1=mem_mostradas(eleccion1,Muestra_part1)
        Muestra_part2=mem_mostradas(eleccion2,Muestra_part2)
        Muestra_part3=mem_mostradas(eleccion3,Muestra_part3)
        Muestra_part4=mem_mostradas(eleccion4,Muestra_part4)

        #Almacen de senales observadas en el diccionario (memoria de senales observadas)
        Observa_part1=mem_observadas(pareja_part1[0], Observa_part1)
        Observa_part2=mem_observadas(pareja_part2[0], Observa_part2)
        Observa_part3=mem_observadas(pareja_part3[0], Observa_part3)
        Observa_part4=mem_observadas(pareja_part4[0], Observa_part4)

        #RONDA 2
        #Probabilidad para cada participante de mostrar una senal determinada en 2a ronda
        Prob_S1_part1 = with_b(Muestra_part1[S1], Observa_part1[S1], s1, round[1])
        Prob_S2_part1 = with_b(Muestra_part1[S2], Observa_part1[S2], s2, round[1])
        Prob_S3_part1 = with_b(Muestra_part1[S3], Observa_part1[S3], s3, round[1])
        Prob_S4_part1 = with_b(Muestra_part1[S4], Observa_part1[S4], s4, round[1])

        Prob_S1_part2 = with_b(Muestra_part2[S1], Observa_part2[S1], s1, round[1])
        Prob_S2_part2 = with_b(Muestra_part2[S2], Observa_part2[S2], s2, round[1])
        Prob_S3_part2 = with_b(Muestra_part2[S3], Observa_part2[S3], s3, round[1])
        Prob_S4_part2 = with_b(Muestra_part2[S4], Observa_part2[S4], s4, round[1])

        Prob_S1_part3 = with_b(Muestra_part3[S1], Observa_part3[S1], s1, round[1])
        Prob_S2_part3 = with_b(Muestra_part3[S2], Observa_part3[S2], s2, round[1])
        Prob_S3_part3 = with_b(Muestra_part3[S3], Observa_part3[S3], s3, round[1])
        Prob_S4_part3 = with_b(Muestra_part3[S4], Observa_part3[S4], s4, round[1])

        Prob_S1_part4 = with_b(Muestra_part4[S1], Observa_part4[S1], s1, round[1])
        Prob_S2_part4 = with_b(Muestra_part4[S2], Observa_part4[S2], s2, round[1])
        Prob_S3_part4 = with_b(Muestra_part4[S3], Observa_part4[S3], s3, round[1])
        Prob_S4_part4 = with_b(Muestra_part4[S4], Observa_part4[S4], s4, round[1])

        probabilidades1 = [Prob_S1_part1, Prob_S2_part1, Prob_S3_part1, Prob_S4_part1]
        probabilidades2 = [Prob_S1_part2, Prob_S2_part2, Prob_S3_part2, Prob_S4_part2]
        probabilidades3 = [Prob_S1_part3, Prob_S2_part3, Prob_S3_part3, Prob_S4_part3]
        probabilidades4 = [Prob_S1_part4, Prob_S2_part4, Prob_S3_part4, Prob_S4_part4]

        #Senales que muestran los participantes en la RONDA 2. Asignadas segun las probabilidades dadas por la ecuacion de memorias
        eleccion1 = choice(opciones, probabilidades1) #senal mostrada por participante 1 en ronda 2
        eleccion2 = choice(opciones, probabilidades2) #senal mostrada por participante 2 en ronda 2
        eleccion3 = choice(opciones, probabilidades3) #senal mostrada por participante 3 en ronda 2
        eleccion4 = choice(opciones, probabilidades4) #senal mostrada por participante 4 en ronda 2

        fichero.write(output.format(i, ######################################## 
                                    eleccion1, ################################
                                    eleccion2, ################################
                                    eleccion3, ################################
                                    eleccion4)) ###############################
```

He movido los `import`s al principio del programa y he eliminado partes innecesarias. Las líneas que hacen el trabajo que pides son las líneas que acaban con almohadillas, ejemplo:

```
linea_que_hace(cosas) #########################################################
```

Comment: Gracias por el interés @kikocorreoso. La solución que aportas es muy útil. Sin embargo, adicionalmente, volviendo a la pregunta, me gustaría saber cómo sacar automáticamente una tablita resumen que contenga la frecuencia con que cada jugador ha elegido cada señal en cada ronda a lo largo del las mil simulaciones. Por otra parte, no sé por qué el archivo CSV me pega el output íntegramente en una sola columna. Como ves, estoy todavía aprendiendo :). Imagino que son cosas fáciles pero me llevan tiempo. Poco a poco.

Comment: el programa te genera un csv que guarda los valores que has indicado que querías. No entiendo  qué te refieres con *'el archivo CSV me pega el output íntegramente en una sola columna'*. Un fichero csv es un fichero delimitado por comas, en cada fila tienes los valores del número de la iteración/generación y los valores que estabas mostrando en pantalla para cada jugador (como se indica en el cabecero) del csv generado. Si detallas exactamente qué esperas en el fichero de salida igual podemos encontrar una solución más adecuada.

Comment: me refiero a que cuando abro el archivo csv generado en excel, por ejemplo, me aparece todo pegado en una misma celda. El ejemplo que has compartido me es muy útil. Pero me gustaría obtener una tabla de las frecuencias. Es decir, saber cuántas veces, en cada ronda, cada jugador, a lo largo de las x simulaciones, ha elegido cada señal.